# How to get duplicate row identifier in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a simple table with `(id, value)` as fields where `value` should always be unique.

On trying to insert duplicate row, how can we get row identifier (`id` here) which is already present in DB ? Preferably in single query ?

Brute force which i am doing right now is:

```
- insert into table
- if @GetGeneratedKeys returns 0, then row is already present
- make another query to get that row
```

Edit: `ID` for new row is autogenerated using `@GetGeneratedKeys` annotation, so not possible to query if `ID` exists or not

Comment: Mybe you mean `IF EXISTS` , You want to check if `ID` is exists then insert another one?

Comment: ```ID``` here is autogenerated using ```@GetGeneratedKeys``` annotation, so not possible to query if ```ID``` exists or not

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ExistingID integer;
SELECT @ExistingID = [ID] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Value] = @SomeValue;
IF @ExistingID IS NULL BEGIN
    --It does not exist yet, do something
END ELSE BEGIN
    --It already exists and @ExistingID holds the ID, do something
END
```

Comment: What are you trying to get done in a single query?  Are you wanting to update a row if it exists, and otherwise insert a new row?  Or just insert if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: If it's already there -> get the row id, else -> insert and get the id of new row.